# Python crash course chp 10: Why does copying and running the json code from the book returns error?

Tags: python

I tried solving a problem that includes json from the python crash course book. However it returns an error I don't know how to solve. Even copying the one of the example programs from the book's github results in an error.

**Here is what I copied to try running from the github/textbook:**

```
import json

def get_stored_username():
    """Get stored username if available."""
    filename = 'username.json'
    try:
        with open(filename) as f:
            username = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
    else:
        return username

def get_new_username():
    """Prompt for a new username."""
    username = input("What is your name? ")
    filename = 'username.json'
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(username, f)
    return username

def greet_user():
    """Greet the user by name."""
    username = get_stored_username()
    if username:
        print(f"Welcome back, {username}!")
    else:
        username = get_new_username()
        print(f"We'll remember you when you come back, {username}!")

greet_user()
```

**And the error it returns:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tonnylin/pythonfiles/remember_me.py", line 31, in <module>
    greet_user()
  File "/Users/tonnylin/pythonfiles/remember_me.py", line 24, in greet_user
    username = get_stored_username()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tonnylin/pythonfiles/remember_me.py", line 8, in get_stored_username
    username = json.load(f)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Poor title; see [ask]. That said, is your json file empty?

Comment: do you have the username.json file saved in the same folder as your python script? how are you calling your python script?

Comment: What is your input?

Answer (score 2):

The error message suggests that there is an issue with the JSON decoding process. It seems that the program is trying to load an empty JSON file, which results in the "Expecting value" error. To fix this issue, you need to ensure that the username.json file contains valid JSON data.

Here are a few steps you can follow to resolve the error:

1. Make sure you have the username.json file in the same directory as your Python script.
2. Open the username.json file and ensure it contains valid JSON data. The file should have the following format: "" (e.g., "John").
3. If the username.json file is empty or does not exist, you can create it manually or run the get_new_username() function to prompt for a new username and generate the file.
   Once you have confirmed that the username.json file contains valid JSON data, the error should be resolved, and the program will run without any issues.